# How do I adapt this .prop to return mutiple href?

Tags: jquery

How do I adapt this jQuery `.prop()` to return mutiple `href` results?

```
window.onload = function() {
  var val = jQuery(".ro_title").prop("href");
  jQuery("#form-field-name").val(val);
```

Comment: Return from what? Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. It's not clear what you're asking. Perhaps if you showed us some HTML....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for a combination of [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toarray/):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var val = jQuery(".ro_title").map(function () { return jQuery(this).prop("href"); }).toArray();
  jQuery("#form-field-name").val(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="ro_title" href="https://example.com/?one">one</a>
<a class="ro_title" href="https://example.com/?two">two</a>
<a class="ro_title" href="https://example.com/?three">three</a>
<hr>
<input id="form-field-name" size="60">
```

Answer (score 0):

With a `each` loop. Through each element containing the `.ro_title` CSS class, concat the `href` property to the `val` variable like this:

```
var val = '';

jQuery(".ro_title").each(function(index) {
     val += jQuery(this).prop("href") + ', ';
});

jQuery("#form-field-name").val(val)
```